# KVObserving a protocol in Swift 4

Tags: swift4, key-value-observing, swift-protocols

I am struggling to use the new strongly-typed KVO syntax in Swift 4 to observe properties that are only visible through a protocol:

```
import Cocoa

@objc protocol Observable: class {
    var bar: Int { get }
}

@objc class Foo: NSObject, Observable {
    @objc dynamic var bar = 42
}

let implementation = Foo()

let observable: Observable = implementation

let observation = observable.observe(\.bar, options: .new) { _, change in
    guard let newValue = change.newValue else { return }

    print(newValue)
}

implementation.bar = 50
```

---

```
error: value of type 'Observable' has no member 'observe'
let observation = observable.observe(\.bar, options: .new) { _, change in
```

Clearly, `Observable` is not an `NSObject`. But I cannot simply cast it to `NSObject`, because the type of the keypath will not match the type of the object.

I tried being more explicit about the type:

```
let observable: NSObject & Observable = implementation
```

But:

```
error: member 'observe' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'NSObject & Observable'; use a generic constraint instead
let observation = observable.observe(\.bar, options: .new) { _, change in
```

Is what I am trying to do not possible? This seems a common use case. It is easily done with old #keypath syntax. Can you offer any alternatives? Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have the same :-(

Comment: I haven't solved it.

Answer (score 12):

This code compiles and runs in Swift 4.1.2 (Xcode 9.4):

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol Observable: AnyObject {
    var bar: Int { get }
}

@objc class Foo: NSObject, Observable {
    @objc dynamic var bar = 42
}

let implementation = Foo()

let observable: NSObject & Observable = implementation

func observeWrapper<T: NSObject & Observable>(_ object: T) -> NSKeyValueObservation {
    return object.observe(\.bar, options: .new) { _, change in
        guard let newValue = change.newValue else { return }
        print(newValue)
    }
}

let observation = observeWrapper(observable)
implementation.bar = 50
withExtendedLifetime(observation, {})
```

All I did is wrap the call to `observe` in a generic function that's constrained to `NSObject & Observable`.

Despite the introduced generic, it’s still possible to pass the protocol-typed `observable` to this new function. To be honest, I can't really explain why this works.

*Edit: This might explain it: [protocols in Swift generally don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/116862), so it wouldn't be allowed to call a generic function with an existential (a protocol type) even if the constraints match. But there's an exception for `@objc` protocols (without static requirements), which do conform to themselves. I suppose this works because `Observable` is marked `@objc`.*

Comment: if you need to flag every property in the class by `@objc`, it is more elegant if you use the `@objcMembers` modifier on the class itself.

Comment: Thank you Ole; your approach does cast some light on the problem. It's still a long shot from the workable solution, because it requires a forced cast `as! (NSObject & Observable)` if we only had `Observable` to start with. And I couldn't figure any way to pass in the key path, because `KeyPath<Observable, Value>` is different from `KeyPath<NSObject & Observable, Value>`.